# Nokogiri::XML parse value based on another XML attribute's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri::XML how can I retrieve a attribute's value based on another attribute?

XML file:

```
  <RateReplyDetails>
    <ServiceType>INT</ServiceType>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
  </RateReplyDetails>
  <RateReplyDetails>
    <ServiceType>LOCAL</ServiceType>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
  </RateReplyDetails>
```

And I would like to retrieve the Price of the LOCAL ServiceType which is 2.0

I could take the value without any condition with this:

```
rated_shipment.at('RateReplyDetails/Price').text
```

And probably I could do something like:

```
if rated_shipment.at('RateReplyDetails/ServiceType').text == "LOCAL"
  rated_shipment.at('RateReplyDetails/Price').text
```

But is there any elegant and clean way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
 <RateReplyDetails>
    <ServiceType>INT</ServiceType>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
  </RateReplyDetails>
  <RateReplyDetails>
    <ServiceType>LOCAL</ServiceType>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
  </RateReplyDetails>
</xml>
EOT

service_type = doc.at('//RateReplyDetails/*[text() = "LOCAL"]')
service_type.name # => "ServiceType"
```

`'//RateReplyDetails/*[text() = "LOCAL"]'` is an XPath selector that looks for the `< RateReplyDetails>` node that contains a text node equal to `"LOCAL"` and returns the node containing the text, which is the `<ServiceType>` node.

```
service_type.next_element.text # => "2.0"
```

Once we've found that it's easy to look at the next element and get its text.

Answer (score 1):

try, `content` is the xml content string.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
doc.at('servicetype:contains("INT")').next_element.content

[16] pry(main)> 
doc.at('servicetype:contains("INT")').next_element.content
=> "1.0"
[17] pry(main)> 
doc.at('servicetype:contains("LOCAL")').next_element.content
=> "2.0"
```

I have test it, it's working.

Comment: Be careful with using CSS `contains` in a selector as it's a sub-string match, meaning that it'll match "INT" or "LOCAL" anywhere in the string, potentially resulting in false-positive matches.

Comment: this should also work for me as my text is very unique there. I selected the first replied and correct answer as the answer but this should work also. thanks guys

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for your remind, actually i know this problem, before i paste this answer, i tried the way you did before, but fail, now i know the correct way to use `text` now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fully in XPath:

```
rated_shipment.at('//RateReplyDetails[ServiceType="LOCAL"]/Price/text()').to_s
# => "2.0"
```

**EDIT:**

> it didnt work for me

Full code as proof it does work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'nokogiri'
rated_shipment = Nokogiri::XML(DATA)
puts rated_shipment.at('//RateReplyDetails[ServiceType="LOCAL"]/Price/text()').to_s
__END__
<xml>
 <RateReplyDetails>
    <ServiceType>INT</ServiceType>
    <Price>1.0</Price>
  </RateReplyDetails>
  <RateReplyDetails>
    <ServiceType>LOCAL</ServiceType>
    <Price>2.0</Price>
  </RateReplyDetails>
</xml>
```

(outputs `2.0`.) If it does not work, then it is because your file contents do not match your OP.

Comment: it didnt work for me - had to go to the parent after the search